# Electric potential $V = kq/r$ derivation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

I want to proof that $V = \frac{kq}{r}$ without using the advanced vector calculus (such as gradient operator, curl, etc.).

First I used the work-energy theorem: $W = \Delta E$

$\Delta W = \Delta U$

where U is the electric potential energy.

$\Delta U = - \int F dr$
then I divided this equation by $q$ so I got this form

$\frac{\Delta U}{q} = - \int \frac{F}{q} dr$

$\frac{F}{q} = E$, $\frac{\Delta U}{q} = \Delta V$

$\Delta V = - \int E dr$

Now, I don't know how to continue on this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working isn't that clear.

The potential is the negative of the work done by the field to bring $1C$ from a point of zero reference (usually set at infinity) to the specified position. That is, $V = -\int_{\infty}^{r} E dx$, assuming we're working in one dimension only.

For an electric field in one dimension, $E = \frac{kq}{x^{2}}$. Consequently,

$V = -\int_{\infty}^{r} \frac{kq}{x^{2}} dx = -\int_{\infty}^{r} kq x^{-2} dx = -[-\frac{kq}{x}]_{\infty}^{r}=\frac{kq}{r}$